# In which conditional statement(loop) condition is not necessary?

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax, conditional-statements, do-while

> In which conditional statement(loop) is the condition not necessary?
>   Options:
>
> 1. `for` loop
> 2. `do while`
> 3. `while`
> 4. none of these

I believe the answer is **4. none of these**. But after lots of suggestion and answers now I am more confused that the answer may be **1. for loop**.

Since in a for loop without condition, it will be treated as infinite loop. But again in **2. do while loop** ..... if I want only to execute once then condition may not be necessary. Well I am not sure so please guide me. Thanks

Comment: I think it is just a syntactical question, you can write `for(;;)` but you can't write `while ()`.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is "1. for loop".

This is a syntactically legal for loop in Java: `for (;;) {...}`.
It behaves exactly the same as `for (;true;) {...}`.

In a do-while loop, a condition is required, e.g.: `do {...} while(true);`.

In a while loop, a condition is required, e.g.: `while(true) {...}`.

Comment: For reference, this property of for loops is described in [JLS 14.14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1), specifically "If the Expression [the part between the semicolons] is not present ... then the contained Statement [the loop body] is executed.".

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf)*:

- `while (boolean-expression) Statement`
- `for ( [ForInit] ; [boolean-Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement`
- `do Statement while ( boolean-Expression )`

So in other words, the `for` statement does not *require* a "conditional statement"

*) added "boolean-" to "expression" for clarity

Answer (score 0):

if by condition u mean to not enter any thing and u know that it will generate an infinite loop then the for loop is the answer theoretically. practically ur loop has to end somewhere maybe memory, time or power drop or any hardware failure can terminate the whole system. so the context of the question is not clear here. Any loop can be used infinitely given some conditions in while and do while loop if continious run is the goal. if you want some piece of code to run again and again there are other workaround you can do. refreshing the page in web programming or setting goto and label (old technique and not a good)